# How can I add a callback to a ThreadedKernelClient in IPython?

Tags: ipython, jupyter

Currently I'm getting my hands on a `ThreadedKernelClient` by:

```
kernel_manager = KernelManager(client_class='IPython.kernel.threaded.ThreadedKernelClient')
kernel_manager.start_kernel()
kernel_client = kernel_manager.client()
```

However, I'm not sure how I can register a callback for incoming messages (after I run `execute`). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done is subclass `ThreadedZMQSocketChannel` and `ThreadedKernelClient`, and overwrote `call_handlers`, eg:

```
class TestChannel(ThreadedZMQSocketChannel):
    def call_handlers(self, msg):
        # do something


class TestClient(ThreadedKernelClient):
    iopub_channel_class = Type(TestChannel)
    shell_channel_class = Type(TestChannel)
    stdin_channel_class = Type(TestChannel)
```

Your manager then looks like:

```
kernel_manager = KernelManager(kernel_name='python', client_class='__main__.TestClient')
```

Once you `start_channels`, your `call_handlers` method will be called with results from methods such as `execute`.